# I need to convert the dictionary to a data frame but its giving me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
stud_dict={'Ali':'Math 90 physics 85','taha':'Math 88 physics 70','lara':'Math 80 physics 90'}

print(stud_dict)

import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({stud_dict})

print(df)
```

Comment: What error, exactly? Also, what is `{stud_dict}` supposed to mean? I guess the error is about `stud_dict` not being hashable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should the result look like? Is this dictionary as given, because it is not very fit for the task.

Comment: thank you guys for helping i found out the problem @ForceBru

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

stud_dict={'Ali':'Math 90 physics 85','taha':'Math 88 physics 70','lara':'Math 80 physics 90'}
df = pd.DataFrame(stud_dict.items(), columns=['Name', 'Desc'])

print(df)
```

Another approach:

```
import pandas as pd

stud_dict = {'Student Name': ['Ali', 'taha'], 'Course Name': ['Math 90 physics 85', 'Math 88 physics 70']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Check this also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: what should i do if i want the row index represented by the student name and columns label represents the course name?

Comment: @RAMA would be better to organize better your structure: d = {'Student Name': ['Ali', 'taha'], 'Course Name': ['Math 90 physics 85', 'Math 88 physics 70']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Comment: it gave me an error, anyways we learned at school that i can define the index and it will change the column name but i stuck at doing it

Comment: @RAMA you can change column name anytime actually. What is the error you are getting? This code works fine for me :)

Comment: create a DataFrame df from the stud_dict, such that the row index represented by the student name and columns label represents the course name.

Comment: this is what i want exactly